# How to get the content of a meta tag of a page in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, meta-tags

I'm working on an app in Android Studio.
In this app there is an WebView where i show a page.
Can I get the content of the "theme-color" meta tag?

Comment: You can download the HTML independently and parse it yourself-  assuming it isn't created via javascript.  But a webview is a black box display element, it isn't meant to be parsing data for you.  If you need to get that kind of data from your server, you should set up an API to get it.

Comment: But via the WebView can I get the title, description and more...

Comment: Yes, you can get a few things.  But that isn't what a webview is made for.Its not an html parser.  Its a display element.  If you want to parse html, use the right tool.  Its not meant for and there are no apis to get random tags inside of an html block in WebView.